# libcurl Multi Threading and SSL

Tags: c++, curl, https, libcurl

I currently have a multi threaded Libcurl application in c++, the application creates around 150 threads using std::thread and the threads load HTTPS urls.

The problem is libcurl uses OpenSSL, and although it's thread safe with the required locking functions, it's not possible to use concurrent connections over HTTPS using OpenSSL. So this kinda defeats the purpose of the threads right?

What is the best work around so I can run multiple threads using HTTPS?

Comment: *"it's not possible to use concurrent connections over HTTPS using OpenSSL"* - why do you say that?  It is certainly possible, even common (do you really think OpenSSL-based servers process clients serially?). As long as each connection is associated with its own SSL object, multiple connections can use OpenSSL in parallel just fine.  What you describe sounds more like a libcurl issue than an OpenSSL issue.

Comment: it is not a libcurl issue either, libcurl supports that just fine as well.